# How to pass an array parameter using NamedParameterJDBCTemplate to a function who takes array['EGY','IND'] as paramters?

Tags: postgresql

My function is `f_wfc_transaction_summary_isocc_ft_sum_no_tid('2015-07-01 14:00:00','2015-07-21 01:00:00', array['EGY','IND'], 'LINK')
where wfc_result in ('TM_OK', 'TM_NO_CHANGE')`

I am using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        params.addValue("isoCountryCode", isoCountryCode ,java.sql.Types.ARRAY ); --> this is the array['EGY','IND']
        result = template.queryForList(overallDataQuery,params);
```

I tried several ways:
1. isoCountryCode field as an array
2. isoCountryCode field as a string of the format - `{'EGY','IND'}`

However, I keep getting postgres errors - String cannot be converted to postgres array type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        params.addValue("featureType", featureType);
        params.addValue("fromDate", fromDate);
        params.addValue("toDate", toDate);
        Array array = null;
        try {
            Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
            array = con.createArrayOf("text", isoCountryCode);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {}
        params.addValue("isoCountryCode", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
result.addValue("arrayParam", list.toArray(new String[0]), Types.ARRAY);
```

Another issue was comparing the array to null because the regular "is null" is not working:

```
and (paramName = any(:arrayParam) or COALESCE(:arrayParam, '{}') = '{}')
```