# Spring SQL-Parameter Mapping (array)

Tags: spring, postgresql

I want to use a parameter called tags in a sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM reply WHERE array[:tags] @> array[2293,2294];
```

I pass the parameter and execute the statement via:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
Integer[] a={2293,2294};
params.addValue("tags", Arrays.asList(a));
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(statement, params, String.class);
```

But it throws the error:

> class org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException No
>   value supplied for the SQL parameter 'tags]': No value registered for
>   key 'tags]'

If I change the statement to:

```
SELECT * FROM reply WHERE '{:tags}' @> array[2293,2294];
```

It throws the error:

> class org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
>   PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT
>   * FROM reply WHERE
>   '{:tags}' @> array[2293,2294]; ERROR: invalid
>   input syntax for integer: ":tags" Position: 72; nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for
>   integer: ":tags" Position: 72

If I change the statement to:

```
SELECT * FROM reply WHERE (:tags) @> array[2293,2294];
```

It throws the error:

> class org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT
>   * FROM reply WHERE (?, ?)
>   @> array[2293,2294]; nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   record @> integer[] Hint: No operator matches the given name and
>   argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Position:
>   81

Comment: Looks like there was a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925109/how-to-pass-an-array-parameter-using-namedparameterjdbctemplate-to-a-function-wh

Answer (score 1):

Separate brackets from :tags solves the problem:

```
SELECT * FROM reply WHERE array[ :tags ] @> array[2293,2294];
```